# BizTalk BAM - How do I track split messages

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

I want the BAM view to show

- IntegrationStart
- MessageType
- ServiceName
- ServiceStart
- ServiceEnd
- IntegrationDuration

The messages comes from one receive port and are passed to an orchestration, one message per orchestration, that sends them to a WCF service.

I know how to solve this scenario if I have one incoming message that goes all the way (different InterchangeID), but I have a batch that the receive pipeline split to individual messages (with the same InterchangeID).

I cannot use a unique value in the message, since there can be more than one in the batch.

I guess I need to use Relationship, but how?

What ID can I relate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did use a relation ship, with the interchangeID, and now everything works fine.

I also created a view so I did not have to change my already created reporting services reports.

When I did not had the relation ship I could get "Violation of primary key",because Bam engine tried to put in records with the same key (after split in receive pipeline all messages have the same interchangeID).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this - http://generatetypedbamapi.codeplex.com. The generated API has methods to create relationships between activities and will do a lot of the work for you...

I would suggest reading this book as well - http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470046422.html. Darren's chapter on BAM is especially good and has clear examples...

Comment: Hi Fabio. Thanks for your reply. This time I have a already deployed and running solution so I need to use TPE. I will have a look in the book to see if it clear things out. Thanks.